# Cut a variable based on another variable - R

Tags: r

I have two variables in my data frame like BloodSugarTestType, BloodSugarReading. Test type can have three values - 'Fasting', 'Random', 'PostPrandial'. Now based on BloodSugarTestType, I need to categorise BloodSugarReading into different ranges.

I am trying like this:

```
DBRiskProfiling.Data[DBRiskProfiling.Data$bld_sgr_ctgry=='Fasting', c('bld_sgr')] <- cut(DBRiskProfiling.Data[DBRiskProfiling.Data$bld_sgr_ctgry=='Fasting', "bld_sgr"], breaks=c(0, 126, 500))
```

Could anyone please help how to do this with cut function??

Example: TestType - **Fasting**
blood sugar reading categories - (0, 126], (126, 300] ##These are levels

TestType - **Random**
blood sugar reading categories - (0, 126], (126, 200], (200, 300] ##these are levels

[What I have is left side table, What I want is right side table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j7vp.png). Sorry as I could not explain clearly.

Comment: sry to bother... I got what I wanted. Thank you all who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not very clear but I am guessing you mean something like this (I don't think what you want can be achieved with `cut()`):

```
# first, create a variable with informative string values for each category (assuming df is your data.frame)
df$reading_cat <- "f1"

df$reading_cat[df$testType == "Fasting" & df$reading > 127] <- "f2"
df$reading_cat[df$testType == "Random" & df$reading < 127] <- "r1"
df$reading_cat[df$testType == "Random" & df$reading >= 127 & df$reading < 201] <- "r2"
df$reading_cat[df$testType == "Random" & df$reading >= 201] <- "r3"

[...and so on for other categories...]

# then recode as factor to assign the labels you want
df$reading_cat <- recode(df$reading_cat, "'f1' = '(0, 126]'; 'f2' = '(126, 200]'; 'r1' = '(0, 126]'; 'r2' = '(126, 200]'; 'r3' = [...]")
```

A few caveats. You will **not** be able to use this variable as an ordered factor as you have overlapping categories and so, for any analysis, you will have to specify custom contrasts.